# What is the baryonic mass distribution of the Milky Way

Tags: mass, milky-way, baryons

There are many, many studies of the Dark Matter halo around the Milky Way but I'm having trouble finding good raw data about visible matter.  I'm investigating a [MOND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Newtonian_dynamics) like model and would like some data uncorrupted with [CDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_dark_matter) assumptions.

Data and/or estimates would be fine just so long as they are uncorrupted with assumptions about cold, dark matter. Many of the papers out there spend a huge amount of their energy trying to estimate the effects of a modelled halo on the actual kinematic data. I'm looking for something that is based on observed (baryonic) matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to reproduce the work of McGaugh (2008, http://arxiv.org/abs/0804.1314 ).

In section 3, they adapt a model (the Tuorla-Heidelberg model), based on observations, for the baryonic mass distribution in the Galaxy. The model is based on a synthesis of a number of observational studies.